# Questions about "interrupt"

Tags: hardware, interrupt

Could someone help me clarify the following conecpts, and ***the relationship among them***?

- Maskable interrupt
- Unmaskable interrupt
- Hardware interrupt
- Software interrupt
- CPU INTR pin
- the IF bit of EFlags register

Some specific questions:

- What's the relationship between Maskable/Unmaskable interrupt and Hardware/Software interrupt?
- What's the relationship between maskability and being software/hardware?
- Is there any unmaskable/software interrupt and maskable/hardware interrupt?
- What kind of interrupts does INTR pin detect?
- What kind of interrupts are enabled/disabled by IF bit of EFlags register?
- What kind of interrupts need the presence of an interrupt controller?

Many thanks.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag as such.

Comment: No~ it's not a homework. I am writing some interrupt service routiens for hobby. And these concepts kind of puzzling me.

Comment: OK, if it really looks like homework, I'll tag it then ;)

Comment: If it is not homework I see no reason for you to add the tag. *Unless of course you were lying and then felt guilty about it. :)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Interrupts

---

Maskable: Can be enabled/disabled by setting the proper bit.

- **Non-Maskable:** Can **NOT** be enabled/disabled. (no designated bit).
- **Hardware:** RST, INTR etc. Whenevr the h/w pin is activated properly h/w INTERRUPT occurs.
- **Software:** An Interrupt raised by using the INTERRUPT software instruction.
- **INTR** pin is Interrupt receive pin.
- All interrupts are handled by the "Interrupt-handler" i.e. Interrupt service routine (ISR). An ISR is a function written, that is executed when an interrupt occurs.
- **IF (bit 9) Interrupt enable flag :** Controls the response of the processor to maskable interrupt requests. Set to respond/enable to maskable interrupts; cleared to inhibit/disable maskable interrupts.

---

A lot more Q & A info here:

> - http://www.techinterviews.com/8086-interview-questions

For a detailed explanation. Plz refer the book ***Microprocessor x86*** by **Barry B Brey**

GoodLuck!!

Comment: Thanks CVS. I will look at more materials and make a summery of that shortly.